# Preventing Arc Discharge

Tags: high-voltage, discharge, arc

I am repairing some ozone generators and one of them has a tower with a discharge path I can't seem to get rid of.  Back in the heyday of television, my dad ran a side (hobby) business repairing bw tv's.  Occasionally, he would use what looked to me (a 5 year old) like red varnish labeled "Corona", not the beer.  Bing isn't giving me extreme happiness finding the product, so I assume it is now history.  Does anyone have recommendations as to what to use?

Comment: "Corona" is an effect, generally not the cause or solution. Unless there's something I don't know (which is entirely possible).

Answer (score 1):

Short for "[Corona Dope](https://www.google.com/search?q=corona%20dope)," also found as high dielectric strength insulating paint.   Corona dope is still sold by the usual electronics chem suppliers.  I find that crazy glue cyanoacrylate works fine.   But note that these painted-on coatings are intended to stop HV leakage across a surface.   If you have sparks leaping across an air gap, then instead you need a thick material rather than paint.

Silicone caulk works fairly well, but use the ammonia-stink RTV type, not the water-base stuff found in paint stores.

Also note that arcing usually causes and is caused by a carbonized surface path.  Make sure to first scrape away any (possibly invisible) damaged insulating surface which has become conductive.